# TD text content not aligning vertically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm working on a small tic tac toe game and i have a problem aligning vertically the content of my TDs. As you can see in the following screenshot i apply the vertical-align property to the selected TD but the text is still not centered vertically and remains slightly below the center of the square.

[image]

How can i align the content of the TDs properly?

I uploaded the source files in this [folder](https://ufile.io/f/xc61f) in case they are needed.

Thanks in advance

---

I attach the relevant code as suggested by the user Maik Lowrey.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row"><div class="column d-flex justify-content-center">
        <table>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div></div>
```

**JS**

```
let cells = document.querySelectorAll("td");
cells[selected_cell].innerText=event.key;
```

This is what i get now, the structure of the grid has changed but the letter is still not aligned vertically:

[image]

Comment: it depends on your `font` and on the set `line-height` so play with those. Try setting `line-height: 1`

Comment: Please add your code to your question and avoid to add your sourcecode over third party.

Answer (score 1):

To center any element inside the container, add below css to the container

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i still have the same problem. Using display: flex modifies the grid structure but as you can see from the new screenshot i attached to the initial post the letter is still not aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use **verticle-align:middle** to table.. it can solve your problem

Comment: This is the real answer.

Answer (score 0):

A way for centering elements is to use `text-align: center` for aligned horizontally. Also set `line-height` equal with `height` of the element for aligned vertically.

**Example**:

```css
.container {
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  line-height: 85px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">1
</div>
```

See: https://www.sitepoint.com/atoz-css-quick-tip-vertical/